# [jetty][WebSocket] Client side connect with some parameters?

Tags: jetty-9

I have a question about WebSocket based on Jetty. Is there any way to capture the parameters companied with client side connect to Jetty Server side?

It looks like the following sample code:

**Client** :

javascript -

```
ws = new WebSocket("ws://localhost/events/member=12345");
```

**Server** :

```
@OnWebSocketConnect

public void onConnect(Session session, String member) {

    // member will get "12345" 
    System.out.println(member);
}
```

Comment: Hey guys,

I've solved by myself.
I just search for Session class api then I found a method called `getUpgradeRequest()`.

After I get the request then I can use `getParameterMap()` to get all parameters from client side constructed as a Map data structure. 

FYI

Comment: Can you please provide code sample please.